# Simple application to aggregate information from multiple web services in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, same-origin-policy

Whats the easiest way to build a simple 'web' application which is a single page, that just refreshes itself (using AJAX or something) to display continuously changing data hosted on various different servers on the internet?

I want to interface with (for example) Twitter, Facebook, Skype, Google Calendar, and any number of other services that have some type of web API.

The application does not need to allow user interaction other than to configure it with the authentication parameters needed to access those services.

It should be able to run full-screen with no UI elements showing, just the pretty information I am displaying.

I started to write an HTML file using Jquery but I am running into "Same Origin Policy" issues.  Is there a way around this?

I'd love to just write this in Html/Javascript and run it in Google Chrome, is that possible somehow?  I don't know how to get around SOP without hosting my own web server as a proxy to cross the domains.

Is there another alternative that is still pretty easy and simple?  I looked into using the Windows Vista Sidebar but apparently you can't have a full-screen gadget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I can use the command line option for chrome:

```
--disable-web-security
```

And it will allow me to workaround the same origin policy, and since I am using this for a local application I can put the app in a virtual machine and let it run without too much worry.